# Cannot change font to "Arial" on Windows CE

Tags: c#, fonts, compact-framework, windows-ce

We're using a Windows CE 6.0 device and programming with the .NET CF v2.0. If I start my application immediately on power up (with a suitable registry setting in HKLM\init), then the following code works on Label controls but fails on ListView controls:

```
cntrl.Font = new Font("Arial", cntrl.Font.Size, cntrl.Font.Style);
```

The failure symptom is that Font.Name is still "Tahoma" even after calling that code for the ListView. No idea why.

Now I edit the registry to stop the application starting immediately on power up. Power cycle the device, wait a few seconds, and manually start my application...now the code works for all control types!

Alternatively I add a shortcut to \Windows\Startup (or the Startup folder specified in HKLM\System\Explorer\Shell Folders\Startup). This loads the application automatically after a few seconds delay, and this works too.

At design-time, controls have a font of "Tahoma", and are being replaced with "Arial" if the language selected by the user is Vietnamese. I attached two images of the application to show the problem.

[image: App launched immediately on power up]

[image: App launched manually a few seconds after power up]

What you will notice is that Label controls are NOT affected, just ListView controls. We have an older stock of Windows CE 5.0 devices running *exactly* the same code...and it works correctly on these devices. This suggests some subtle timing issue on Windows CE 6.0.

Finally, this only affects "Arial" and Vietnamese. Mandarin (using the "Droid Sans Fallback" font) and Thai (using the "Loma" font) both work correctly on all devices.

Any ideas? Is there something I can do to force fonts to be loaded, or perhaps wait until fonts are loaded?

Comment: Curiously, if I prevent the application loading via the registry and instead put an application shortcut into the device Startup folder, then Vietnamese fonts work correctly in the ListView! There is a noticeably longer delay between powering up and my application start of ~2-3s using this latter method, but the delay is not too severe. This strongly suggests there is some part of the CE 6.0 OS that is not properly initialised until a second or two after power up.

Comment: There are some API that are loaded on startup. These are not available directly and so the OS will signal, when these API are ready to use: WaitForApiReady: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482994%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx. You did not write which 'startup' you are using. If HKLM\init, there are more dependencies to wait for than if using \Windows\StartUp.

Comment: @josef: The device supplier has put our application into HKLM\init (I'll edit the question with that info).

Comment: After a few more tests, I've found that I can delay (using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);) in Program::Main before launching my application. After that, Vietnamese works fine. Oddly, I only need to do this if I am running on Windows CE 6.0 (and not 5.0) and using a language which requires the "Arial" font (Vietnamese and Hebrew in my build). Languages using the built-in "Tahoma" font or Asian languages using "Droid Sans Fallback" do not need the delay.

Comment: Following on from previous comment, you might be interested to know that Sleep(2000) or less continued to fail. Sleep(2500) was mostly reliable and Sleep(3000) or higher worked every time. Does CE 6.0 need a bit more time before its ready-to-rumble compared with 5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an application is started using HKLM\Init you have to ensure that all needed APIs and resources your app uses is ready. There are several ways to control that:

- the order number of the init entry
- the depends value of your app
- the WaitForAPIReady function

For example:

The shell32.exe process is reg key [HKLM]\Init\"Launch50"="shell32.exe" and the depends entry for this is "Depend50"=hex(3):14,00,1e,00. That means that the OS will launch shell32.exe when the processes behind Launch20 (0x14) and Launch30 (0x1e) hav signaled there start. In the example Launch20 is device.exe (driver loader) and Launch30 is gwes.exe. That means that the OS will ensure that shell32.exe will not be started before both these processes have signaled there start and load is complete.

If you Create an entry Launch51 with Depend51=0x14,00,0x1e,00 the process for Launch51 will also not be started before the required processes signaled there readiness.

Further on, if you are using a shell or GWES API function, you must ensure that the function is ready to be used. So you need to call WaitForAPIReady to check that, otherwise your app may fail to start or run correctly. Extra font loading may depend on GWES and GDI and so you should wait for SH_GDI. GWES loading is already checked with the Depend entry.

Even if you put your process to start via a lnk file in Windows\StartUp you may need to use WaitForApiReady. Some resources may still not be available early in the startup process. This is more a case the sooner a process is started, as for example via HKLM\init.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know on which API the controls inside Compact Framework rely on.

Comment: Corrected my typo WaitForAPIReady. DLLImport has not been added by me.

Comment: See josef's answer for the background to the problem. See my own answer for code specifics to use "WaitForAPIReady" (on CE 6.0) or "IsAPIReady" (on CE 5.0) using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on josef's answer:

```
* Use "WaitForAPIReady" (not "WinApiReady") on Windows CE 6.0 (or higher)

* Use "IsAPIReady" on CE 5.0 (or earlier)

* If using C# (which I was using) then you'll need to P/Invoke the functions:

    // If using Windows CE 6.0 (or higher)
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern uint WaitForAPIReady(uint uAPISlotIndex, uint uTimeout);

    // If using Windows CE 5.0 (or earlier)
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsAPIReady(uint hAPI);

* Define these constants:

    // If using Windows CE 6.0 (or higher)
    private const uint SH_GDI           = 80;
    private const uint SH_WMGR          = 81;
    private const uint SH_SHELL         = 85;

    // If using Windows CE 5.0 (or earlier)
    private const uint SH_GDI           = 16;
    private const uint SH_WMGR          = 17;
    private const uint SH_SHELL         = 21;

* If you need to be signalled that the OS is ready run this code:

    // If using Windows CE 6.0 (or higher)
    WaitForAPIReady(SH_GDI, 5000);
    WaitForAPIReady(SH_WMGR, 5000);
    WaitForAPIReady(SH_SHELL, 5000);

    // If using Windows CE 5.0 (or earlier) (IsAPIReady is a polling function)
    int nTimeout = 0;
    while ((!IsAPIReady(SH_GDI)) && (nTimeout++ < 50))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

    nTimeout = 0;
    while ((!IsAPIReady(SH_WMGR)) && (nTimeout++ < 50))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

    nTimeout = 0;
    while ((!IsAPIReady(SH_SHELL)) && (nTimeout++ < 50))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

* Finally, to be absolutely sure the OS is ready, I pause for 1s more

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```